# Can I Add States, Transitions, Properties if a QStateMachine is already started?

Tags: qt, qstatemachine

I have some problem with states aren't setting properties. Probably the problem is because I add the properties after the machine is started and I'm adding to the current state. But I need to add properties, states and transition when the machine is already running. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just understood the problem. Properties are set when you enter the state. I need to exit the state and than enter again. Transition and state can be added after QStateMachine starting.

With my application I can go to another state but I would like to know if there is a simple solution to exit and enter from the same state. I'll check if I can do that with  QHistoryState.